# Plugin: Custom menu item problem

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, menus, oop

I'm using the following snippet to add a menu item:

```
<?php
add_menu_page(
    'Foo Server',
    'Foo Server',
    'manage_options',
    'foo-server',
    array('Class', 'method')
);
?>
```

Fine, it's displayed. But clicking on it returns:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I really don't know what to do.

Any idea? Thanks

UPDATE: Problem fixed. I was registering the menu using the wrong hook:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'function that runs the above code!');
```

must be:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'function that runs the above code!');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you logged in with an administrator account?

Comment: Post your Update as Answer and mark it as solution in the following days. Else it would stay open forever.

Answer (score 1):

Hook into `'admin_menu'` to register menu pages. And next time [prepare your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) better.

Answer (score 0):

Do your WordPress Database Tables use wp_ as a prefix? I've read several articles that using a different prefix can cause the permissions error.

**Source:**

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-45

http://beconfused.com/2007/how-to-solve-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: I've read about something like that. I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: *************************************************************** Hey what's up with the down vote? Maybe the person that down voted the answer should post why they decided to give me a negative mark. I think it should be required. If you don't "share your brilliance", then your not helping anyone. Everyone has to start somewhere. I always try to help others not just be a prick to those that know less than me. *********************************************

Comment: I've tried both links. This doesn't work for my case. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy Jared - Don't get upset. I voted it to zero again. I'm more _angry_ about how this Q was asked and how the solution appeared...

Answer (score -2):

If you're calling this from inside a Php Class, then you're using the wrong syntax:

```
add_menu_page(
    'LiveHelp Server',
    'LiveHelp Server',
    'manage_options',
    'livehelp-server',
    // Call the  the method/function from inside a class
    array( __CLASS__, 'method_name' )
    // Another way to call the method/function from inside a class
    array( &$this, 'method_name' )
    // Another way to call the method/function from inside a class
    ClassName::method_name
);
```

Be sure that your method/function is really named `method()` (which is a bad idea). Else it won't work.

I guess you're simply calling it from inside a function, so it's enough to name the callback function (without a class).

---

*Note: If you need further assistance, read about classes and functions on php.net. The Q itself is not really a Wordpress Q.*

Comment: I'm not using the same class to do that! It's another class. I really know how call_user_func acts. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you want to provide your whole code?

Comment: Sorry Kaiser, it was me. I guessed it was you that down-voted my answer. I've see you've responded to my reply concerning the down-vote. I don't want you to misunderstand me. I have no problem with being down-voted, but I stand by what I posted. If you are going to criticize then it should be constructive criticism. I'm sure you were taught that somewhere in your design career. I wasn't upset for the negative vote, just that you didn't take the time to explain why. I see that a lot here, and it really makes the "down-voter" seem arrogant and as I said doesn't really help anyone but themselves.

Comment: Oh, but I was the one who downvoted the OP. Not providing code is fishing in the dark. And that's not kool.

Comment: When the 16 hours are up I'll return the vote. It doesn't make my reply "shallow" though. I stand by what I said. I tried to apologize, but I see it's not accepted. I returned to own up to my down vote if that's what mean by "shallow words". Anyway, I had good intentions (making a point), I just messed up and acted before I was sure. I guess only the mystery voter knows. No hard feelings... life goes on.

Comment: Sry, then it was a missunderstanding (and forgot about the 16h). I'll remove the comments.